# How to get the FunctionAppDirectory in Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder) in Azure function

Tags: azure, azure-functions

In Azure function i can get the FunctionAppDirectory from the context but How do I get the FunctionAppDirectory  in Configure method.

I need FunctionAppDirectory at `<<FunctionAppDirectory>>` in the code:

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <copyright file="WebJobsExtensionStartup.cs" company="Microsoft">
// Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
// </copyright>
//  --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using Intercom.Helpers;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
using Microsoft.Azure.KeyVault;
using Microsoft.Azure.Services.AppAuthentication;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.AzureKeyVault;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[assembly: WebJobsStartup(typeof(ConvAi.BfChannel.BotManagementService.WebJobsExtensionStartup), "Web Jobs Extension")]
namespace ConvAi.BfChannel.BotManagementService
{
    /// <summary>
    /// WebJobsExtensionStartup
    /// So this Azure function should be deployed with App service plan.
    /// </summary>
    public class WebJobsExtensionStartup : IWebJobsStartup
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// AzureServiceTokenProvider which is used for requesting identity token.
        /// </summary>
        public static AzureServiceTokenProvider AzureServiceTokenProvider { get; set; }

        /// <summary>
        /// Configure services.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="builder">WebJob Builder</param>
        public void Configure(IWebJobsBuilder builder)
        {
            try
            {
                bool isLocal = string.IsNullOrEmpty(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID"));

                // Gets the default configuration
                var serviceConfig = builder.Services.FirstOrDefault(s => s.ServiceType.Equals(typeof(IConfiguration)));
                var rootConfig = (IConfiguration)serviceConfig.ImplementationInstance;


                var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                    .SetBasePath(<<FunctionAppDirectory>>)
                    .AddConfiguration(rootConfig)
                    .AddJsonFile($@"Config\botregistrationOptions.{rootConfig["environmentName"]}.json", optional: false)
                    .Build();

                // Replace the existing config
                builder.Services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //log
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can replace `context.FunctionAppDirectory` with `Environment.CurrentDirectory`.

At least, that works locally and that's exactly where you need `local.settings.json` to work, so this change should be safe.

When you would use it on azure, you need to add `.AddEnvironmentVariables()` to `config`.

Update:

Use the following code when you work both locally and azure.

```
var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(<<FunctionAppDirectory>>)
    .AddConfiguration(rootConfig)
    .AddJsonFile($@"Config\botregistrationOptions.{rootConfig["environmentName"]}.json", optional: false)
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .Build();
```

Comment: we have 3 different json files per environment, So I want it to work both locally and in azure.

Comment: @JitendraSinghRathor, I have update my reply you could refer to.

Answer (score 1):

See here for a good explanation how to handle app settings in Functions v2: https://blog.jongallant.com/2018/01/azure-function-config/

Bottom line: For local debugging you usually use a local.settings.json file. When deployed in Azure, you don't use config files, but instead the app settings are injected as environment variables into your Function. One huge advantage of that is that you can use things like Azure Key Vault integration of secure storage of settings: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references